# Orthogonal Projection Tensor

Tags: tensors

Hi my question is about this orthogonal projection tensor $P^\sigma_\nu\equiv\delta^\sigma_\nu+U^\sigma U_\nu$.

It should have the following properties when $V,W$ are vectors parallel and perpendicular to U, and $U$ is a 4-velocity in spacetime.  These equations come from (1.121) and (1.122) in Sean Carroll's gravity book.

$
P^\sigma_\nu V^\nu_\parallel ~~= ~~0
$

$
P^\sigma_\nu W^\nu_\perp ~~=~~ W^\sigma_\perp
$

However, when I test for the first property I do not get the correct answer.  I suppose I am messing up how I am using the Kronecker delta but I'm not sure how.  Lets operate on and a vector $V$ that is parallel to $U$ to get the "equal zero" condition above.

$
P^\sigma_\nu V^\nu_\parallel ~~=~~\delta^\sigma_\nu V^\nu_\parallel+U^\sigma U_\nu V^\nu_\parallel
$

If $\sigma=\nu$ then $\delta^\sigma_\nu=1$.

$
P^\sigma_\nu V^\nu_\parallel~~=~~ V^\sigma_\parallel +U^\sigma U_\sigma V^\sigma_\parallel  \qquad \qquad [U^\sigma U_\sigma=-1]\\
\quad\qquad=~~ V^\sigma_\parallel - V^\sigma_\parallel \\
\quad\qquad=~~0 \quad\checkmark
$

That looks good, now let's check when $\sigma\neq\nu$ and $\delta^\sigma_\nu=0$.

$
P^\sigma_\nu V^\nu_\parallel~~= ~~0 +U^\sigma U_\nu V^\nu_\parallel  \qquad \qquad~~~ [V\parallel U\implies U_\nu V^\nu\neq0]\\
\quad\qquad~\neq~~ 0  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad~~~~~~ [\mathrm{contradicts~Eq.}(2)]
$

It looks like I should totally disregard the case where $\sigma\neq\nu$ but I don't see why.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about $\sigma=\nu$ and $\neq \nu$ are ill defined. $\nu$ is a dummy index in the Einstein summation convention so you are, at best, describing terms in the sum. The real cases are about the inner product $V^\nu U_\nu$, because $\delta^\sigma_\nu V^\nu = V^\sigma$ always.

Comment: Thank you.  I am just confused how the delta in the polynomial can also control the indices in the term that it is not multiplied with.  Could you say a little more?  That seem to violate the interpretation of the delta as a tensor.  I am reviewing and I don't remember too well.  It's just a rule that if a delta appears anywhere, it contracts the index in $\delta^\sigma_\nu V^\nu=V^\sigma$ and ALSO all it changes all the other instances of $V^\nu$?  That is hard for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: Nope. The other $\nu$ is contracted with the $U$. So, it works like this:$$\begin{align}P_\nu^\sigma &= \delta_\nu^\sigma + U^\sigma U_\nu\\
P_\nu^\sigma V^\nu &= (\delta_\nu^\sigma + U^\sigma U_\nu)V^\nu\\
& = \delta_\nu^\sigma V^\nu + U^\sigma U_\nu V^\nu \\
& = V^\sigma + U^\sigma U_\nu V^\nu. \end{align}$$ So, the only question is how $V$ is related to $U$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.  $V$ is parallel to $U$.  How does that ensure that the second term is zero giving the expected $P^\sigma_\nu V^\nu=V^\sigma$?

Comment: The thing is that $V$ is not always parallel to $U$. For a general vector, $V$, you can decompose it into a part that's parallel and a part that's perpendicular to $U$: $V = V_{||} + V_{\perp},$ where the defining equation of $V_{||}$ is $V_{||}^\mu = a U^\mu$ for some constant $a$. So: how do we find $a$? Once we have $a$, how do we construct $V_{\perp}$? What happens to the equation when we plug this broken down version of $V$ into it?

Comment: LOL I'm all confused.  I think I got it now despite the error in my comment above.  My previous comment is so wrong!  I completely forgot what I was even talking about.  Thanks again.  $PV=0$ is what I was looking for, not $PV=V$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is the following: by applying the operator $P^{\sigma}_{\nu}$ to the vector V this is what you are actually doing:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{\nu=0}^{3}P^{\sigma}_{\nu}V^{\nu}=\sum_{\nu=0}^{3}(\delta^{\sigma}_{\nu}+U^{\sigma}U_{\nu})V^{\nu}
\end{equation*}
From which follows:
\begin{equation*}
P^{\sigma}_{\nu}V^{\nu}=V^{\sigma}-V^{\sigma}
=0\end{equation*}
As you correctly stated in the beginning of your question. The point is that $\nu$ becomes a dummy index only $\textbf{after}$ the operator is contracted on the vector.

Answer (score 1):

$P^{\sigma}_{\nu} V^{\nu} = V^{\sigma} + U^{\sigma} U_{\nu} V^{\nu}$ holds generally for a vector $V^{\nu}$.

Now, if we additionally assume that $V^{\nu}$ is parallel to $U^{\nu}$, then its components are just those of $U^{\nu}$ but scaled by some number $\beta$, i.e: $V^{\nu} = \beta U^{\nu}$.

Therefore, $U^{\sigma} U_{\nu} V^{\nu} = \beta U^{\sigma} U_{\nu} U^{\nu} = - \beta U^{\sigma} = - V^{\sigma}$, using the fact that the norm of the 4-velocity is -1 ($U_{\nu} U^{\nu} = -1$).

It follows that $P^{\sigma}_{\nu} V^{\nu} = V^{\sigma} - V^{\sigma} = 0$, if $V^{\mu}$ is parallel to $U^{\mu}$.